# Mock Angular Material MatCheckboxChanged Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I need to pass a mocked checkbox event into a method under test.

```
manageCheckboxStates(event: MatCheckboxChange, spreadItem: SpreadItem): void {
if (this.checkboxManager.length > 0) {
  this.checkboxManager.forEach(id => {
    const index: number = this.checkboxManager.indexOf(id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      if (event.checked) {
        this.checkboxManager.push(event.source.id);
      } else {
        this.checkboxManager.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  this.checkboxManager.push(event.source.id);
}
```

}

The event object source property is actually what is giving me problems.
From the API:

```
/** Change event object emitted by MatCheckbox. */
export declare class MatCheckboxChange {
/** The source MatCheckbox of the event. */
source: MatCheckbox;
/** The new `checked` value of the checkbox. */
checked: boolean;
```

}

I am not finding a way to mock this due to the MatCheckbox constructor args:

```
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor, _ngZone: NgZone, tabIndex: string, _clickAction: MatCheckboxClickAction, _animationMode?: string | undefined);
```

Any strategies to approach this would be appreciated.  I just need to provide the parameter so I can get at the `event.checked` and `event.source.id` properties that are required to test the method.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was so wrapped up in the complexity of MatCheckbox that I overlooked simplicity.  I refactored the method signature to take what was required from the event and passed in those values from the template instead of the entire object.  Then it was simple to test the method, passing in a sourceId and checked values.

```
manageCheckboxStates(sourceId: string, checked: boolean): void {
if (this.checkboxManager.length > 0) {
  this.checkboxManager.forEach(id => {
    const index: number = this.checkboxManager.indexOf(id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      if (checked) {
        this.checkboxManager.push(sourceId);
      } else {
        this.checkboxManager.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  this.checkboxManager.push(sourceId);
}
```

}